# Refinery - NoMethodError: undefined method `spec' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, refinerycms

When I was installing refinery 3.0.0, at the end of the bundle process the error:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `spec' for nil:NilClass
An error occurred while installing refinerycms-core (3.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
```

was shown.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The solution was to install the latest version of bundler:

```
gem install bundle
```

I hope it helps

Comment: Personally, I think the issue would be fixed by `gem cleanup bundler`, but Cris' solution is also valid.